# koma script, scrartcl keywords for the abstract

Tags: koma-script, abstract, keywords, scrartcl

I am a newbie in Latex and Koma scripts.

I would like to add **Keywords: bla, bla, bla** just under the abstract with the same format in scrartcl class.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that "just under the abstract with the same format" means the same format as the abstract itself. AFAIK the KoMa classes don't provide a macro/environment for keywords but I would just put the keywords as part of the abstract.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My Work}
\author{Me Myself}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[66]
\par\vskip\baselineskip\noindent
\textbf{Keywords: bla, bla, bla.}
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you the response.  Your solution at least gives a newline. But any formatting is being stripped  off  by abstract environment like bold. I need to give a line of space between the abstract and the keywords, \newline, \\, do not affect any formatting in abstract environment. I believe I need to redefine existing abstract environment and enhance it according to keywords, but I do not know how to do it. Thank again for the response.

Comment: No formatting is stripped off, because no formatting is not put in. If the whole keyword line should pe bold then put the whole line in `\textbf`, as in `\textbf{Keywords: bla, bla bla}`. And for a line of space replace `\medskip`in my code by `\vskip\baselineskip`.

Comment: @user1155710 See edit.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have tried the file you provided and it does what its supposed to, however in my article it does not, maybe because of  some other stuff in the preamble of the document. Thank you again for sparing time. I have marked this as solution.